# Storing user session data into a customized database

Tags: symfony1

It's possible to [store user session](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer) in database by changing the settings in factories.yml:

```
all:
  storage:
    class: sfMySQLSessionStorage
    param:
      db_table:    session              # Name of the table storing the sessions
      database:    propel               # Name of the database connection to use
      # Optional parameters
      db_id_col:   sess_id              # Name of the column storing the session id
      db_data_col: sess_data            # Name of the column storing the session data
      db_time_col: sess_time            # Name of the column storing the session timestamp
```

From the example given, it seems that the columns in the table are limited to a few predefined ones. Which means that it's not possible to store other information that Symfony doesn't anticipated, such as ip address.

Is it possible to extend the database schema to include more custom columns?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own session class like this

```
class myPDOSessionStorage extends sfPDOSessionStorage {
    /**
    * Extending session write function
    *
    * @param string $id Session identifier  
    * @param mixed $data Session's data
    */
    public function sessionWrite($id, $data){
        /*
          Handle your specific data, e.g. :
        */
        $mySession = new MySession();
        $mySession->setIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_IP']);
        // connect with org. session
        $mySession->setSessionId($id);
        // Save extended session - you for sure need to add logic in finding existing one's
        $mySession->save();

        // IMPORTANT Call Parent function to update original session data
        parent::sessionWrite($id, $data);
    }
}
```

In factories.yml :

```
all:
  storage:
    class: myPDOSessionStorage
    db_table:    my_session # Name of the table storing the sessions
    database:    my_session # Database connection to use
```

This was a basic example, so you'll find further informations here :

- http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_storage
- http://www.designdisclosure.com/2009/11/symfony-doctrine-database-session-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Not directly; the structure of a session is very limited, though you can store quite a bit of data *within* the session. Symfony just stores the session data as a blob in the db. You could try modifying the sfMySQLSessionStorage class to include the $_SERVER['REMOTE_IP'] in the session table if you really need it.